# Redirects for Ember app on shared hosting (hostgator)

Tags: ember.js, html5-history

I have an ember app that I have been building. It has several routes including index (`/`) and authorization (`/authorization`). My trouble is that when the application is hosted on hostgator, loading the url `myapp.com/authorization` results in a 404. This makes sense since there is nothing at that actual url. I need hostgator to redirect all non-file-specific urls to my index.html file.

An example in psuedo code:

```
if url has extension (.jpg, .pdf, etc)
    serve requested url
else
    serve index.html but retain url in the address bar
```

I've done this sort of thing with local instances of node when using AngularJs with ui-router, but this is my first time using History-API based routing served from HostGator.

Any suggestions on where to start to set this up?

Comment: Does Hostgator allow you to set a htaccess file or equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but you can use locationType: 'hash' in environment.js as your configuration.

With locationType set to 'auto', refreshing on application hosted on Hostgator will produce a 404. I have encountered this before and not found any solution. So I switched to 'hash'.

If you find any solution, please tell me. Thanks!